# How would I make a chrome extension to block each tab's favicons?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, favicon

I'm trying to replace all favicons with a Chrome extension with some Javascript. In order to do that I need to find the dom element that contains the favicon.

On most websites I can do something similar to this:

`document.querySelector('link[rel="icon"]').href = "//data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="`

However on some websites such as apple.com, I can't figure out the dom element that contains the favicon by just viewing the page source, how would I go about blocking the favicon in that case?

Answer (score 0):

I realized I was going about this all wrong. Instead of trying to replace the html element after the page was loaded, I should just block the network request which fetches the favicon.

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function(details) {
    return {cancel: ["favicon.ico", "favicon"].includes(details.url.split('/').pop().split('?')[0].split('@')[0]) };
  },
  {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
  ["blocking"]);
```